# DataTable no muestra popup cuando esta filtrado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo en un proyecto ASP MVC y estoy usando el [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) para administrar elementos de un catalogo por medio de ventanas Modal de bootstrap, las ventanas modales se disparan a través de etiquetas a, **actualmente cuando el DataTable solamente tiene cargado 10 elementos todo funciona bien, pero cuando tiene por ejemplo 11 y quiero administrar el 11 la ventana modal no se carga** como tal:

Este es un ejemplo del DataTable:

```
    <table id="example" class="ctrlLineTable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="ColorHeaderTable">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Secuencia)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                Acciones
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="ColorHeaderTable">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Secuencia)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                Acciones
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class="celda">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Secuencia)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Descripcion)
                </td>
                <td class="celda" style="width: 20%">
                    <a style='color: #004881; text-decoration: none' href='/etapabase/edit/@item.EtapaBaseId' id='etapau-@item.EtapaBaseId' title='Editar información de la Etapa Base'>
                        <span class='fa fa-pencil fa-lg'> </span>
                    </a>
                    <b style='color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
                    <a style='color: #004881; text-decoration: none' href='#' id='etapad-@item.EtapaBaseId' title='Eliminar información de la Etapa Base'>
                        <span class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'> </span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Por medio de este script estoy abriendo los modales:

```
    $('#example tbody tr td a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("entro");
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Como mencione todos los modales se abren perfectamente hasta que llego al 11avo ahi la ventana modal se abre como si fuera una vista normal.

Comment: Hola jose luis, ¿haz verificado si la otra pregunta propuesta es un duplicado o si se trata de una pregunta diferente?